# Extract title from multiple urls in python scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am using multiple links but I not able to fetch title in each link:

```
import scrapy

from ..items import EbayurlItem

class StarterAutomotive(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'starterautomotive'

    start_urls = [
        'http://www.ebaystores.com/DB-Electrical-Starters-Alternators/Starters-Automotive-/_i.html?_fsub=3656448&_sasi=1&_sid=67094701&_trksid=p4634.c0.m322'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
    
        div = response.css('.rs_box')

        for ebay in div:

            href = ebay.css('.ttl a::attr(href)').extract()

            yield response.follow(href, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

            
    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):

        items = EbayurlItem()

        ff = response.url

        print (ff)

        div1 = response.css('h1.it-ttl::text').extract()

        items['div1'] = div1

        yield items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hohe its may help you.

```
import scrapy


class StarterAutomotive(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'starterautomotive'
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.ebaystores.com/DB-Electrical-Starters-Alternators/Starters-Automotive-/_i.html?_fsub=3656448&_sasi=1&_sid=67094701&_trksid=p4634.c0.m322'
    ]
    def parse(self, response):

        href = response.css('#lvc > table > tr > td > div.ttl>a::attr(href)').extract()
        for url in href:
            yield response.follow(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        print(response.url)
        div1 = response.css("#itemTitle::text").extract()
        yield {'title':div1}
```

Here is some output.

```
{'title': ['New CDI Module For Mercury / Mariner 40-125HP Marine Engines 332-5772A7']}
2020-06-24 06:23:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Starter-5-0L-5-0-6-2L-6-2-Ford-F150-F250-F350-Pickup-14-15-16-2014-2015-2016-/143329630069?vxp=mtr&hash=item215f1c9775> (referer: http://www.ebaystores.com/DB-Electrical-Starters-Alternators/Starters-Automotive-/_i.html?_fsub=3656448&_sasi=1&_sid=67094701&_trksid=p4634.c0.m322)
2020-06-24 06:23:30 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Starter-5-0L-5-0-6-2L-6-2-Ford-F150-F250-F350-Pickup-14-15-16-2014-2015-2016-/143329630069?vxp=mtr&hash=item215f1c9775>
{'title': ['New Starter 5.0L 5.0 6.2L 6.2 Ford F150 F250 F350 Pickup 14 15 16 2014 2015 2016']}
```

Comment: Please see the link https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work , there is a tick mark click on it.